# How to get logs for a message after a particular revision number in Sharpsvn

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

I using Sharpsvn for getting svn log details in c#. I have written the following code :

```
using(SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
    Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> list;
    SvnLogArgs la = new SvnLogArgs { Start = 128};
    client.GetLog(new Uri("http://my/repository"), la, out list);

    foreach(SvnLogEventArgs a in list)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("=== r{0} : {1} ====", a.Revision, a.Author);
       Console.WriteLine(a.LogMessage);
    }
}
```

I want to get the logs for revision number given in start till the latest revision number. This is giving me all the logs of the svn url. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this. The thing was to replace `Start` with `End` in `SvnLogsArgs{}`.